# error in terraform module | can any one help me in finding the syntax error? While running these modules getting syntax error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

Can anyone help me in finding syntax error in the above terraform code snippet?

[image: Can anyone help me in finding syntax error in the above terraform code snippet?]

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 1):

In your variable `egress_rules` under `default` you have `[{` while it ends with `]}`. If you move `[{` to `{[` it should work.